# Looking for name of common numbered lists

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

I'm looking for any recognized name or perhaps to coin a term that that refers to a proper name given for a list of things that is regularly defined by the number of things in a list:

> - Seven Deadly Sins
> - Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse
> - Seven Wonders of the Ancient World
> - Five Stages of Denial

Has anyone heard of a name for what these are called?

If you had to come up with a name, what would it be?
Enumeronym?  (Hate pairing Latin and Greek roots, but...)

Comment: found this if it helps : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fictional_quartets

Comment: This is a good one

Comment: Related: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NumerologicalMotif

Answer (score 1):

"Enumeration" or "enumerated set" generally describes such a list.  I'm not aware of any more precise word for it.  As for creating a word for it, as you asked, I'd say you're on the right track using "enumerate" as the root word.  "Enumerism" perhaps, which follows a similar construction as euphemism, criticism, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably the best off with *enumeration*.

But you could also use *tally* or plural, *tallies* depending on your style requirements.

See both [enumeration](http://www.freethesaurus.com/enumeration) and [tally](http://www.freethesaurus.com/tally) in the thesaurus.